# Using jQuery, I want to get the values of two radio groups, if any of it's values changed

Tags: jquery

I want to listen both the change events of radio groups. If anyone of it changes,I need to send them through ajax.

```js
$('input:radio[name=emp_m_status]','input:radio[name=emp_gender]').change(function() {
  var gender = document.getElementByName("emp_gender");
  var married = document.getElementByName("emp_m_status");
  console.log(gender, married);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

emp_m_status:
<br>
<label><input name="emp_m_status" type="radio" value="Married" checked>Married </label><br/>
<label><input name="emp_m_status" type="radio" value="Divorced">Divorced </label><br/><br/> emp_gender:

<br>
<label><input name="emp_gender" type="radio" value="Male" checked>Male </label><br>
<label><input name="emp_gender" type="radio" value="Female">Female </label><br>
```

Comment: tried already but not working? Any JSFiddle you have this? Thanx if yes.

Comment: @DaraNaveenKumar You have to provide sample replicating your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector is wrong. You are using [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) instead use [Multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$('input:radio[name=emp_m_status],input:radio[name=emp_gender]')
                               //^^
```

Also `input` is redundant in the above selector.

Additionally, use [`:checked` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to get the selected radio value.

```
var emp_m_status = $(':radio[name=emp_m_status]:checked').val();
```

```js
$(':radio[name=emp_m_status],:radio[name=emp_gender]').change(function() {

  var emp_m_status = $(':radio[name=emp_m_status]:checked').val();
  var emp_gender = $(':radio[name=emp_gender]:checked').val();

  console.clear();
  console.log('emp_m_status: ', emp_m_status);
  console.log('emp_gender: ', emp_gender);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

emp_m_status:
<br>
<label><input name="emp_m_status" type="radio" value="Married" checked>Married </label><br/>
<label><input name="emp_m_status" type="radio" value="Divorced">Divorced </label><br/><br/> emp_gender:

<br>
<label><input name="emp_gender" type="radio" value="Male" checked>Male </label><br>
<label><input name="emp_gender" type="radio" value="Female">Female </label><br>
```